# Parsing Tab delimited text files

Tags: c#

I have a **tab delimited** file with some columns and rows for example: some rows might not have value for some columns. 
What we know is that the "order" doesn't change so always third tab delimited thing is for Column3 and so on.

```
Column1  Column2  Column3 .... Column12 .... Column34 ... Column50
123  34 ABC
234     DEF                                   as@ddd.com    True
     45           NYC                         wwe@dsds.com  False
```

Now I need to read this file but not all of the columns are important for my program. For example I only need to do some stuff with values in Column2, Column12,Column45

What approach do you suggest?

Comment: read line by line, split on tabs, grab the columns that you need.  What else are you looking for exactly?

Comment: Are you looking for opinions or are you having trouble with a particular part of the problem?

Comment: @Jonesy I don't know this part: " grab the columns that you need" 
Also what's an efficient way of reading the file that doesn't crash or go out of memory if file is big?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try following approach

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
    StreamReader streamreader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Temp\txt.txt");
    char[] delimiter = new char[] { '\t' };
    string[] columnheaders = streamreader.ReadLine().Split(delimiter);
    foreach (string columnheader in columnheaders)
    {
        datatable.Columns.Add(columnheader); // I've added the column headers here.
    }

    while (streamreader.Peek() > 0)
    {
        DataRow datarow = datatable.NewRow();
        datarow.ItemArray = streamreader.ReadLine().Split(delimiter);
        datatable.Rows.Add(datarow);
    }

    foreach (DataRow row in datatable.Rows)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(""----Row No: " + datatable.Rows.IndexOf(row) + "----"");

        foreach (DataColumn column in datatable.Columns)
        {
            //check what columns you need
            if (column.ColumnName == "Column2" || 
                column.ColumnName == "Column12" ||
                column.ColumnName == "Column45") 
            {
                Console.Write(column.ColumnName);
                Console.Write(" ");
                Console.WriteLine(row[column]);
            }
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: wow..beautiful :) Is there any final thoughts, considerations you might have? Or looks good to you and I go and use it?

Comment: I'm curious why you went with this answer over @Sudhakar's?  In my opinion it's much more simple

Comment: @Jonesy correct, I am still evaluating them all. Right now not sure why this answer didn't keep the order of the records it prints the same as what was in the input file....

Comment: @Jonesy Tried that too, it crashes.

Comment: @DevWannaBe - I don't know what you meant by order of records not maintained. I updated the code to display the row index from the input file. I hope this helps you see what the order of each row is in the input file.

Comment: Thanks @BinayaRegmi . My test file has 12154 rows. So maybe not all of them just showing in the console and scroll bar of console shows a limited set of them? because the first row number I see in the output of console is row 12081

Answer (score 8):

Don't roll your own. There are...subtleties that aren't immediately apparent. Among others:

- quoted fields?
- data containing embedded field and/or record separators
- wrong length recordes
- etc.

Instead, use something like Sebastien Lorion's most excellent [Fast CSV Reader](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader) from [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com).

**Edited to note:** Despite the name, this is a general-purpose reader for delimited text files. Configurable items include

- field separator character
- record separator character
- quote character (for quoted text)
- escape character (for embedded quotes)
- where or not commenting is allowed. If enabled, the comment character (see below) starts a comment, ended by the next record separator.
- comment character (by default, '#')
- whether or not the first line is a header, containing field names.

Comment: thanks but mine is tab delimited text file. The one you suggested is for CSVs?

Comment: The only difference is your choice of field and record separators. Just configure it to use HT (`'\t'`) instead of comma (`','`) as the field separator.

Answer (score 6):

```
var list = from row in System.IO.File.ReadLines("file.txt")
           let arr = row.Split('\t')
           select new Tuple<string, string, string>(arr[2], arr[12], arr[45]);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Incredibly simple, and easy to manipulate after getting the data. I like @Sudhakar Tillapudi answer as well if you wish to have a proper data model. Reading line by line seems so daunting, just give me all the data. The issue here would be if you wanted to read out every single column of a file that has many columns

Answer (score 5):

You can use [File.ReadLines()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method (if you are using .NET Framework Version 4.0 or above) without any performance penalty as it would not load whole file content into Memory.

Try This:

```
using System.IO;

class FileData
{
public string Column2{ get; set; }
public string Column12{ get; set; }
public string Column45{ get; set; }
}


List<FileData> filedata =  new List<FileData>();

 FileData temp = new FileData();
 foreach(var line in File.ReadLines("filepath.txt").Skip(1))
 {     
   var tempLine = line.Split('\t');
   temp.Column2 = tempLine[1];
   temp.Column12 = tempLine[11];
   temp.Column45 = tempLine[44]; 
   filedata.Add(temp);
 }
```

Comment: A list of a defined object structure would likely be better than three independent lists of values :)

Comment: How can I ignore the first line of the file? which is for column names..the next rows are data but first row is column names
Column1  Column2  Column3 .... Column12 .... Column34 ... Column50

Comment: @DevWannaBe: Either convert the `foreach` to a `for` and skip the first line, or introduce a counter or flag variable.  Something like `var skip = true` and then in the loop `if (skip) { skip = false; continue; }`.  Either way would work, it's just a matter of what you consider more readable/supportable.

Comment: why not just `File.ReadLines("filepath.txt").Skip(1))`?

Comment: @Jonesy: Good Point, Edited my post

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi : Crashes, templine is an array with one member and it is a "" empty string.

Comment: @DevWannaBe: are you getting any runtime exception? change `"\t"` to `'\t'`

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi yeah that I changed. But like I said , templine is an array with one member and it is a "" empty string so there is index out of range exception right where we want to read those arrays.

Comment: @DevWannaBe: this code works well if the file really uses coulmns delimited by `tabs` please make sure that wether columns are delimted by collection of spaces or `tab`.Please note that 3 to 4 spaces is not equalent to `tab`, you can split the string using `\t` only when you use tabspace as delimter but not when there are 3-4 spaces.

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi I turned on this thing in NotePad++ that shows spaces and tabs and yes they are tabs.

Answer (score 2):

Just read all lines of your file, then split on tab delimiter, to gain access to each column.

```
   var fileArray = File.ReadAllLines(myLocation);
    
        for(int i=0;i<fileArray.Length;i++)
        {
           var line=fileArray[i];

           if (i == 0)
           {  
              //handle column names
           }
           else
           {
             var columns = line.Split('\t');
             string value = columns[3];
           }
        }
```

Comment: The file might be big, Is there a more efficient way so we can read one line at a time?

Comment: Use `File.ReadLines(myLocation)` instead.

Comment: Modified answer to handle column names too

Comment: in for(int i=0;i< line<fileArray.Length;i++)
what is "line" it doesn't even compile :(

Comment: sorry, was a typo from my earlier answer

Comment: Incomplete example - You need to define what line is.

Answer (score 2):

As Nicholas said, don't roll your own as there are subtleties and special cases.

An option is `TextFieldParser`.

```
using (var parser = new TextFieldParser(filePath))
{
    parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
    parser.SetDelimiters("\t");

    while (!parser.EndOfData)
    {
        var cols = parser.ReadFields();
        // Can now access columns, eg cols[0]
    }
}
```

Comment: This required .net5.0.