# Entity Framework core seed large data from file

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

In EF Core 2.1 I can seed data this way:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().HasData(
  new Company {.....},
  new Company {.....});
```

But I need to seed a text file with a large amount of rows (about 70k).
What do you recommend me to achieve this?

Comment: Does the text file already exist?  If so, what format?

Comment: Text file. Tab separated

Comment: I don't think seeding is suitable for such tasks. Esp. since (as far as I experienced) the seeded data are always validated when a model is built.

Comment: Yes, I seed all data like my example and is VERY slow because validation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What format is the data in this text file in?

If it's in JSON, you could do something like:

```
var companies = new List<Company>();
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"C:\temp\data.json"))
{
    string json = r.ReadToEnd();
    companies = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Company>>(json);
}

foreach(var company in companies)
    dbContext.Companies.Add(company);

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I think this is the beach approach because the seed in the regular way is VERY slow because EF validate the data and check if exists every item. This is OK for seed the database for first time when I migrate. I just add if (!context.companies.Any()) and then seed like your example. Thanks.

Comment: Where do you put that code? It can't be in the migration's `Up` because there is no `DbContext`.

Comment: @RichardBarraclough I think the way is described below 'before EF Core 2.1' section: https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/migrations/seeding

Answer (score -4):

Ok, here's a pretty good explanation: [Parsing Tab delimited text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23225973/parsing-tab-delimited-text-files)

Just add your inserts into the database after each "record".

Comment: I know how to read a txt file, parse and save into the database. My question is what is the best approach to seed large volume of data.