# Reading HTML from Tab Delimited Text File Into String Using C#

Tags: c#, html, decode, encode

I'm trying to read HTML from a tab delimited text file and creating an HTML file which I then convert to a pdf. When I try to read the text file, I get weird characters for ' and some other characters. Here's my code

```
        var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\temp\Laura.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1255"));
        var csv = lines.Select(x =>
        {
            var parts = x.Split('\t');
            return new Articles()
            {
                id = parts[0].Trim(),
                name = parts[1].Trim(),
                body = parts[2].Trim(),
                //body = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(parts[2].Trim()),
                //body = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(parts[2].Trim()),
                //body = WebUtility.HtmlEncode(parts[2].Trim()),
                //body = SecurityElement.Escape(parts[2].Trim()),
            };
        }).ToList();
       foreach (var item in csv)
        {
            string id = item.name;
            string filename = item.name + ".html";
            string body = item.body;
            string path = @"c:\temp\" + filename;

            // This text is added only once to the file.
            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                // Create a file to write to.
                File.WriteAllText(path, body);
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application ap = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
                Document document = ap.Documents.Open(path);

                object oFalse = false;
                object oTrue = true;
                object OutputFileName = Path.Combine(
                Path.GetDirectoryName(path),
                Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path) + ".pdf");
                object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
                document.PrintOut(
                oTrue,          // Background
                oFalse,         // Append
                ref missing,    // Range
                OutputFileName, // OutputFileName
                ref missing,    // From
                ref missing,    // To
                ref missing,    // Item
                ref missing,    // Copies
                ref missing,    // Pages
                ref missing,    // PageType
                ref missing,    // PrintToFile
                ref missing,    // Collate
                ref missing,    // ActivePrinterMacGX
                ref missing,    // ManualDuplexPrint
                ref missing,    // PrintZoomColumn
                ref missing,    // PrintZoomRow
                ref missing,    // PrintZoomPaperWidth
                ref missing     // PrintZoomPaperHeight
                );
            }
        }
```

I have tried the code that's commented out but nothing seems to work.

Comment: any example input and expected output?

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23225973/parsing-tab-delimited-text-files

Comment: @laura-bejjani what are you getting  � like this ?

Comment: @MohamedElrashid - Yes that's exactly what I'm getting for every '. I'm getting similar things for other characters. After I run var parts = x.Split('\t'); and look at parts so I'm guessing some encoding/decoding needs to be done before that line.

Comment: @BagusTesa - I'm passing a file with an ID, File name, and some html that has an ' in it.

Comment: do you use excel , on windows for csv creation or what do you use ?

Comment: @MohamedElrashid - Does it make a difference? I think I used Excel to create the tab delimited text file.

Comment: OK that an encoding problem 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\temp\Laura.txt",  Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1255"));
var csv = lines.Select(x =>
{
    var parts = x.Split('\t');
    return new Articles()
    {
        id = parts[0].Trim(),
        name = parts[1].Trim(),
        body = parts[2].Trim(),
    };
}).ToList();
```

try this wdExportFormatPDF

```
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"1.html", Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1255"));
var path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"2.html");
var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
var doc = app.Documents.Open(path, false);
var OutputFileName = Path.Combine(
                          Path.GetDirectoryName(path),
                          Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path)+
                          ".pdf");
doc.ExportAsFixedFormat(OutputFileName, WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF);
```

here the full code

```
static void connvert()
{
    var lines =
        File.
        ReadAllLines
        (@"C:\temp\Laura.txt",
            Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1255")
        );

    var csv = lines.Select(x =>
    {
        var parts = x.Split('\t');
        return new Articles()
        {
            id = parts[0].Trim(),
            name = parts[1].Trim(),
            body = parts[2].Trim(),
        };
    }).ToList();



    foreach (var item in csv)
    {
        string id = item.name;
        string filename = item.name + ".html";
        string body = item.body;
        string path = @"c:\temp\" + filename;

        // This text is added only once to the file.
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            // Create a file to write to.
            //  File.WriteAllText(path, body);
            File.WriteAllText(path, body, Encoding.Unicode); // try this
            //   File.WriteAllText(path, body, Encoding.Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1255"));// then this

            var app = new Application();
            var doc = app.Documents.Open(path, false);
            var OutputFileName =
                Path.Combine(
                    Path.GetDirectoryName(path),
                    Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path) +
                    ".pdf");
            doc.ExportAsFixedFormat
                (OutputFileName,
                    WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF
                );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this works great. My code then goes into opening the file in word and saving it as pdf. When it opens in word I get some more weird characters phoneâ€™s  (These are also present in the pdf file)

Comment: what file ? Laura.txt

Comment: I updated the question with the full code. The html file that gets created

Comment: if id=1 the file is "c:\temp\1.html" how are creating this file ? can you add the code for creating the file 1.html

Comment: I updated the post with the full code. The code below is where the file is opened with word                 
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application ap = new 
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
                Document document = ap.Documents.Open(path);

Comment: where is WriteAllText

Comment: Sorry I accidentally deleted it while pasting. Its above Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application ap. I fixed it now.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help. The code is much cleaner than mine but the issue is still there. The problem is happening at this level var doc = app.Documents.Open(path, false); If you open the html that gets created with word you will see the same issue and those characters make it to the pdf once the html file is converted.

Comment: @LauraBejjani try  File.WriteAllText(path, body, Encoding.Unicode) or File.WriteAllText(path, body, Encoding.Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1255"))

Comment: Yup this one as Encoding.Unicode. I have a small issue. The html I'm getting (in the Laura.txt file body field)  has whitespace and tabs is there a way to remove that?

Comment: str.Replace(' ', ',') ?

Comment: Another issue is images don't make it from the html to the pdf file.

Comment: I think str.Replace will replace all the tabs. I don't want all the tabs replaced since this is a tab delimited file. I don't think I need to worry about replacing the tabs and spaces. I just need to make sure the images that work in the html file make it to the pdf. Do I need to pass a parameters to include images?

Comment: do still need help?

Comment: Yes please. I still can't get those images to show in the pdf.